# Refreshing Duplicate table in power bi

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

Do my duplicate tables from query will refresh when I will refresh my query? Or its just static duplicate
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a duplicate query is an independent query and must be refreshed on its own..